# Python script not reading from Arduino correctly

Tags: c, arduino

I'm trying to get my Arduino to send data to a python script on my computer and for some reason the python script is reading the data incorrectly. Specifically, it reads the data correctly for about 4-5 receives then it starts to get out of sync. Below is my code:

Arduino:

```
struct sensorData
{
    char beginPad[5];
    int data0;
    char pad0;
    //int data1;
    //char pad1;
    //int data2;
};

union data
{
    unsigned char buffer[sizeof(sensorData)];
    sensorData vars;
};

data sendData;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    static char temp[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    memcpy(sendData.vars.beginPad, temp, 5);
    sendData.vars.pad0 = 0;
    //sendData.vars.pad1 = 0;
}

void loop()
{
    sendData.vars.data0 = (256);
    //sendData.vars.data1 = (512);
    //sendData.vars.data2 = (1024);
    Serial.write(sendData.buffer, sizeof(sensorData));
    delay(100);
}
```

Python:

```
import serial

class SensorData:
    def __init__(self, ser_obj, s_dict, p_start, p_len):
        self.ser = ser_obj
        self.sensor_buffer = s_dict
        self.num_sensors = len(s_dict)
        self.pad_start = p_start
        self.pad_len = p_len
        self.wait_for_beginning(p_start)

    def poll(self):
        for i in range(self.num_sensors):
            tmp = self.ser_read()
            tmp+=(self.ser_read()<<8)
            print tmp
            self.sensor_buffer.values()[i].append(tmp)
            self.ser_read()
        return self.sensor_buffer

    def ser_read(self):
        while True:
            try:
                data = ord(self.ser.read())
                break
            except:
                continue
        return data

    def wait_for_beginning(self, start):
        while True:
            while(self.ser_read() != 0): continue
            flag = 0
            for i in range(1, self.pad_len):
                if i == self.ser_read(): continue
                else:
                    flag = 1
                    break
            if flag: continue
            else: break

    def wait_for_end(self):
        while True:
            pad = self.ser_read()
            if pad == self.pad_len-1:
                break

#END OF CLASS
#main.py

def serial_poll( s_dict ):
    dev = serial_init()
    s = SensorData( dev, s_dict, 0, 5 )
    while True:
        sensor_buffer = s.poll()
        s.wait_for_end()
        print sensor_buffer

def serial_init():
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.baudrate = 9600
    ser.port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
    ser.open()

    return ser

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global sensor_buffer
    sensor_buffer = { 'sensor1': [] }

    serial_thread = threading.Thread( target=serial_poll, args=(sensor_buffer, ) )
    serial_thread.daemon = True
    serial_thread.start()

    while True:
        time.sleep( .1 )
```

I'm running the serial functions on a new thread because I have other things going on in this application. I'm basically trying to send some data that I have hard coded from the Arduino to a Linux computer. I have padding in between actual data to delimit it. At first I thought I was getting buffer overflows since each data buffer was more than 14 bytes long. I shortened it and the issue persisted. I then tried to add a delay since it might be sending data too fast. This didn't help either and now I'm out of ideas. If you need me to be more specific just let me know.

Comment: You should say more about what you mean by "out of sync." It looks more like the problem might be on the Python side, as the Arduino side is pretty simple. You should add a Python tag to the question. Also, `char` is 1 byte, so `data0 = 256;` is the same as `data0 = 0;`.

Comment: By out of sync I mean it would print:
256
256
256
256
1
0
17789
328
*garbage*

Comment: I'll post an output when I'm at home